# About WH_CBT hook

Tags: c++, winapi, setwindowshookex

I'm trying to use `SetWindowsHookEx` to install `WH_CBT` hook on global to inject the DLL into other process. Now I have the inject.exe, ExampleWindow.exe, inject.dll, let me show you the code.

1.code piece of inject.exe

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HHOOK hhook = NULL;
    HMODULE dll = LoadLibrary(_T("D:\\projects\\CppDemon\\Release\\HookDemoDll.dll"));
    HOOKPROC pfn = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(dll, "MyCBTProc");
    if (pfn == NULL)
    {
        printf("can not get MyCBTProc,press any key to exit\n");
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    printf("press any key to continue hook\n");
    getchar();
    hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, pfn, dll, 0);
    if (NULL == hhook)
    {
        printf("%d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    printf("press any key to unhook\n");
    getchar();
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
    return 0;
}
```

2.code piece of inject.dll

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT MyCBTProc(_In_ int nCode, _In_ WPARAM wParam, _In_ LPARAM lParam);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

LRESULT MyCBTProc(_In_ int nCode, _In_ WPARAM wParam, _In_ LPARAM lParam)
{
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}



BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    DWORD pid = 0;
    TCHAR buffer[128] = { 0 };
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        pid = GetCurrentProcessId();
        _stprintf_s(buffer, 128, _T("[+] PID = %d"), pid);
        OutputDebugString(buffer);
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

The ExampleWindow.exe is a test case for inject when the named window is created.

When I run inject.exe and everything goes well, the inject.dll has been loaded and the the debug message is output correct, and the PCHUNTER(this is an ARK tool) can detect the WH_CBT message hook in module inject.exe. Then, I run the ExampleWindow.exe, there also can output the debug message.

After this action, I refresh the message hook windows in PCHUNTER ,the WH_CBT hook message has disappeared from the control, and the inject.dll not injected in the ExampleWindow.exe at all.THis is not my expect result.

I don't know how this happens. I hope someone can help me find the cause of this problem.

Comment: There is an spelling error:alse should be also

Comment: In my case ,the inject.dll just have printed the debug message and it seems to be 'freed' immediately by some unknown reason

Comment: Hard to guess what "refresh the message hook windows" could possibly mean.  Do note that this code does not just inject a single process, it injects all of them.  Well, all of the ones that can load that DLL, bitness is a painful problem on a 64-bit OS today.  The only reason you can see the OutputDebugString text at all is because you also injected your own injector :)

Comment: Calling `_stprintf_s` is not one of the things [you would want to do when inside `DllMain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices).

Comment: @IInspectable I don't agree with you that _stprintf_s isn't safe in DLLMain. It is not mentioned (maybe as a part of CRT memory management functions?) in the link you provide. Furthermore I use it a lot in my hooks without any problems. My hooks inject their code after the injected process have been initialized (already running). So I think it's safe to assume that CRT has been properly loaded and initialized when my hook enters its DLLMain (the case when using SetWindowsHookEx). Can you please elaborate on why it should be unsafe? What string (TCHAR) manipulation functions would be safe then?

Comment: @vuv: Calling `_stprintf_s` from `DllMain` is unsafe, because it is not explicitly listed to be safe. There is no requirement that this function will not result in loading  a DLL as part of its operation (e.g. to satisfy the active locale's National Language Support infrastructure, or by executing the invalid parameter handler routine).

Comment: @IInspectable theoretically yes, but in this case CRT will be initialised by DLLmainCRTStartup (if entry point is not modified) first. Therefore it’s highly unlikely that _stprintf_s can cause such a problem with this or any hook in general.

Comment: it's not the business about _sprintf_s.

Comment: It's not the business about _sprintf_s.My code was just running properly after i put the SetWindowsHooEx in an exported function in a dll.I just load the dll and call the export function ,and then ,the thing goes well....the dll can also inject into other process while specified events happens